# Swift 2.2 Array conforms to protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

I'm receiving a Dictionary of type [String: Any] and I wanna check if value in the dictionary is an Array that conform's to a certain protocol:

```
protocol ToDictionary {
    var badjoras: Bool { get set }
}

struct Badjoras: ToDictionary {
    var badjoras: Bool
}

let newArray: [String: Any] = ["First": [Badjoras(badjoras: true)]]

for (key, value) in newArray {
    if let newValue = value as? [ToDictionary] {
        print(true)
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in Swift 3.0, but in Swift 2.2 it does not. Any ideias on how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of checking "value as? [ToDictionary]" try check like "value as? [Badjoras]"

Comment: The thing is I can receive an array of any type, not just "Badjoras" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following :

```
protocol ToDictionary {
    var badjoras: Bool { get set }
}

struct Badjoras: ToDictionary {
    var badjoras: Bool
}

let newArray: [String: Any] = ["First": [Badjoras(badjoras: true)]]

for (key, value) in newArray {
    if value is [ToDictionary] {
        print(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But does not work either :(